# Phusion Passenger RequestHandler issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I'm running ror app(rails 2.3.5,ruby 1.8.7) on my vps.
Whenever I restart my apache server all the working subdomains are going down. I've passenger version as 4.0.5, I wonder what would be the reason. I'm pasting my apache error log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [this page on the Phusion Passenger wiki](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems) for solutions.

Also, you should upgrade to the latest version (4.0.29) which fixes many bugs and brings many improvements. The error message in the latest version actually links to the page that I linked to.

Comment: Thanks Hongli, It was useful